# Creating tags based on people rather than technology [jon-skeet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, users

I don't want to incur the wrath of gods or create a controversy.

[Singleton implementation laziness with static constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415882/jon-skeet-singleton-implementation-with-static-constructor) is a good question with a newly created tag [jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jon-skeet). It's a good way to seek attention from Gods of SO but is it the right way to do? 
The OP does cry for Jon's help and his prayer was answered promptly :-P

> Jon - please come to the rescue!

So I request burnination of [jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jon-skeet)

Comment: *It's a good way to seek attention from Gods of SO.* No, it isn't, I'm afraid. You could try sacrificing a unicorn instead.

Comment: But does it justify creating a tag? I dont want to be the one who tried to delete Jon skeet. But this might have an implication on a long run.

Comment: Are you actually saying that the tag [tag:jon-skeet] was created and you're asking to burn it? In that case, hell yeah.

Comment: Yep... want to burn `jon-skeet`

Comment: Stack Overflow needs more Jon Skeet, but less [[tag:jon-skeet]].

Comment: I did not add this tag to get any attention. Jon asked me to open a new question so I knew anyway that he's going to respond. I added the tag because the question is regarding special Jon Skeet's implementation of singleton. So actually "he" is an integral part of the question.

Comment: Now that the question has been modified in a drastic way since its initial revision, the (down)votes most likely don't reflect the current question anymore...

Comment: Thanks for noticing... but i deserve it for trying to burn Jon. I should have guessed Jon always comes back alive.

Comment: @Matt - They do... The tag was newly created today, and already removed so the tag won't survive the night. There isn't anything to burninate

Comment: @CarbineCoder I'm a little surprised the system didn't detect it and ban you automatically ;-)

Comment: @Matt - Except this question has gotten more down votes since the edits (and your comments) so maybe some Meta users actually do think creating tags for users is acceptable? The score was -11 or -10 when you originally commented, now it's -16.

Comment: @BSMP Even I don't understand the logic of the new down votes.

Comment: @BSMP - Given the votes on the accepted answer it fortunately does not seem like that. The downvotes are most probably for the direct question '*...is it the right way to do?*' and therefore absolutely appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @Matt - The last line of the post says, *So I request burnination of jon-skeet* so all the down votes appear to be disagreement that the tag shouldn't be on the site. Your explanation makes sense but the down votes themselves still don't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no point in creating a tag on a person, unless the name is synonymous with a programming technology or detail, otherwise all questions under that tag would be off topic.

For example, [Ada Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace), an English mathematician from the early 1800's, has a [technology](http://www.adapower.com/faq/) created in her name. As such, the tag [ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ada) is made to categorize those posts.

Comment: I would say *even* if their name is synonymous with a a programming technology or detail. That's why we have `[tex]` instead of `[knuth]` and `[emacs]` instead of `[stallman]`.